# Is there a way to stop or interrupt the windows shutdown process

Tags: windows, powershell, shutdown

When I call `Stop-computer` or `(Get-WmiObject - Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Win32Shutdown(1)` in powershell, is there a way to stop or interrupt the process before the power is turned off? This means the shutdown process already started, but is not yet finished.

Comment: try `shutdown -a`

Comment: I mean after the shutdown procedure started

Comment: of course after the shutdown procedure started, otherwise you don't need to stop it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you've executed a delayed shutdown (`shutdown /t 60`), you can use `shutdown /a` to cancel the pending event. If the machine is actively shutting down (you have the shutdown screen in-front of you with the in-progress animation on screen), all you can do is hope an open program won't close so you get the opportunity to cancel. If that doesn't happen, you're headed to reboot town.